# Why am I getting pagination twice when I fill my yahoo table

Tags: javascript, yui

Why am I getting pagination twice when I fill my yahoo table? I am deleting my yahoo table before I fill it. I just want to inform you that the table fills with the right data.

```
var MedicalFilesTable = document.getElementById('MedicalFilesTable');     
if(MedicalFilesTable.hasChildNodes())
{
   while(MedicalFilesTable.childNodes.length >= 1)
   {
      MedicalFilesTable.removeChild(MedicalFilesTable.firstChild);       
   }
}

YAHOO.example.MedicalFilesTable = function()
{
   var MyColumnDefs = [           
   {key:"eventid", label: "Event Id",sortable:true,formatter: YAHOO.widget.DataTable.formatAxsOppLink},   
   {key:"PartOfAMulti", label: "Multi?",sortable:true,formatter: YAHOO.widget.DataTable.formatAxsOppLink}                           
   ];

   var MyDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource(gMedicalFilesArray);
   MyDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSARRAY;
   MyDataSource.responseSchema = {fields: ["eventid","PartOfAMulti"]};                           

   var MyConfigs = {paginator : new YAHOO.widget.Paginator({rowsPerPage: 10})};                           
   var MyDataTable = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable("MedicalFilesTable", MyColumnDefs, MyDataSource,MyConfigs);    

   return {oDS: MyDataSource, oDT: MyDataTable};
}();
```

Answer (score 0):

The pagination might not be a child node but another object/property that gets generated to the DOM. try replacing your "MedicalFilesTable" with a new DOM Object.

try to reset the paginator object.. like

```
var MyConfigs = {};
MyConfigs = {paginator : new YAHOO.widget.Paginator({rowsPerPage: 10})};
```

Comment: It is a child node in the generated HTML. The whole thing is working in FireFox but not in IE. The pagination only appears twice when I continue clicking the link many times.

Comment: try to reset the paginator object.. like
var MyConfigs = {};
MyConfigs = {paginator : new YAHOO.widget.Paginator({rowsPerPage: 10})};

Comment: I tried it but it didn't work. Still getting pagination twice.